# how to choose the base windows image when create windows docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

For some reason, we have to build windows based docker. from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows), we know there are 4 types of base image we could build from.

1. windows/nanoserver
2. windows/servercore
3. windows
4. windows/iotcore

I am sure I am not IOT relevant, so windows/iotcore is excluded. while it is not sure about the remains three. it seems from size perspective (nanoserver < servercore < windows). I should try in this order. by now, my service will not start in 1 neither 2. i have to try 3.

what are the criteria to choose between them?

clearly, I am missing some dll to start the service, while dependencywalker seems also not work in the base image 1 and 2.  do someone have experience on how to identify this missing DLL? in this way, it still is possible to use minimize base image with the missed dll.

Progress update:
My service succeed run with #3(windows base image). but the docker image size is very very large. see following. this makes the choice important.

> mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver             10.0.14393.2430     9fd35fc2a361        15 months ago       1.14GB
>   mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore             1809-amd64          733821d00bd5        5 days ago          4.81GB
>   mcr.microsoft.com/windows                        1809-amd64          57e56a07cc8a        6 days ago          12GB

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you've probably moved on by now but essentially

**IOT** - tiny, for builders and maker boards.

**Nanoserver**  = smallest. running netcore apps. you have to build it using multi stage builds. It's quite advanced from what I see to get working.

**ServerCore** = middle.  GUIless windows server. Is the most common default base image. You've not said what service is not running but it's possible that including the App Compatability FOD might solve the problem without increasing the size as much. Use newest container. 1903 I think it is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/install-fod-19

**Windows** = fattest, the whole shebang